# React call Render by html page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made a project in React and HTML5. Previously, to call my render function I had put my render into a global function like this:

```
window.shareRenderResetResult = function () {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div> hello </div>,
        document.getElementById('salut')
    );
};
```

and I called it in my html page like this:

```
<script>
    shareRenderResetResult();
</script>
```

Today, for an another project, I have do the same things but I now get a warning in my console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: shareRenderResetResult is not defined
>       at (index):207 (anonymous) @ (index):207

I don't know what to do. Ideas?

my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>h</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JS/test.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/materialize-css/bin/materialize.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/materialize-css/bin/materialize.js') }}"></script>


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0b3dc57bca.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div id="salut">

    </div>
</div>
 <script>
    console.log("what's wrong with you ?");
        shareRenderResetResult();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have put a console.log in my function but nothing appeared.

Comment: try to `console.log('something');` inside the *shareRenderResetResult* function & check if it works

Comment: can you provide the whole html file? I guess you might call the function before you assign to global

Comment: Seems like the call to `shareRenderResetResult` is called before `window.shareRenderResetResult` is being sat

Comment: i have put my html page and test to put a console.log in my function shareRenderResetResult. but nothing appeared
thx for your help

Comment: anyone else have an idea ?? i have checked the calling function but it's not that ... i'm very tired of this problem